# Highlight the Active Cell, Row but specific column in excel - vba code

Tags: excel, vba

```
sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = x1ColorIndexNone

Target.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 88
Target.EntireColumn.Interior.ColorIndex = 89  
Target.Interior.ColorIndex = x1ColorIndexNone

End Sub
```

- instead of selecting the active entire column, I need to select another column F

Comment: Range("F" & Target.Row) maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

colorIndex 88 and 89 does not exist, but the code below works.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal target As Range)
If target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
Cells(target.Row, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I wouldn't advise using ColorIndex, since it changes the color if the user changes their theme.  Use the RGB value, so that it's reliable.

Comment: @FrankBall, Nope, `ColorIndex` refers to much older settings using a so called pallet and that doesn't change when you change the theme. If you use `Interior.ThemeColor`, the color changes. @Loveb: Disabling `ScreenUpdating` is not necessary when you change only the color of a cell.

Comment: @FunThomas , I took the code from a larger code and you don't want any unnecessary delay, so... @David, if you want to use rgb, you write `.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)`

Comment: There is no extra delay as with or without disabling, there is exactly one screen update. Disabling ScreenUpdating makes only sense if you modify the sheet multiple times and should be handled with an error handler so that you ensure that it's always enabled, even if a runtime error occurs.